# Formula Query within Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to be able to perform the following formula in Excel, I have values for T2, T1, m, Cp and dT but am struggling with regards to the integration formula, is this even possible in excel? Any help appreciated.

Kind Regards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel won't do integration directly. However, you can use an approximate method such as the trapezium rule, to evaluate the integral.

Some instructions for doing this are [Here](http://www.myengineeringworld.net/2013/06/integration-in-excel-trapezoidal-rule.html)

Comment: Rob, many thanks! You wouldn't happen to know how I could apply the above using this method, would you?

Comment: What are the values you have?

Comment: atm no specific values, say  Q(1254) = m(30) x 4.18(Cp) x 10(dT)

Comment: These numbers make no sense in the context of the question.